# Collapsing toolbar issue title staying at top of screen and not collapsing Android

Tags: java, android

The title on the toolbar does not expand and collapse with the collapsing toolbar layout it just stays to pined next to the nav drawer button. 
The collapsing works i just need the title to animate with the expanding and collapsing of the tool bar can anyone help on this issue

Ive tried to set the the title programmatically with the following code but to no avail. Variable has been binded to the layout with findViewById CollapsingToolBarLayout.setTitle("title);

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="left">

    <RelativeLayout
        style="@style/MatchParentMatchParent"
        android:background="@color/color_white">

        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

                <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout_collapse"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
          <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              style="@style/ToolBar"
              app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
              app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
              app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"                    
              app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <androidx.percentlayout.widget.PercentRelativeLayout
        style="@style/MatchParentMatchParent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/home"
            style="@style/WrapContentWrapContent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_back_selector"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc_back_button"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/vd_nav_drawer"
            app:layout_marginLeftPercent="4%"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_toolbar_title"
            style="@style/ToolBarTitle"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/home"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_default_padding"
            android:gravity="left"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative_toolbar_buttons"
            style="@style/WrapContentWrapContent"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:importantForAccessibility="no"
            android:scaleType="center"
            app:layout_marginRightPercent="4%">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_toolbar_primary_button"
                style="@style/WrapContentWrapContent"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:padding="@dimen/dimen_small_padding"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_toolbar_secondary_button"
                style="@style/WrapContentWrapContent"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_small_padding"
                android:padding="@dimen/dimen_small_padding"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:src="@drawable/vd_outline_info_24dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_toolbar_button"
                style="@style/MatchParentMatchParent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/color_toolbar_text"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.percentlayout.widget.PercentRelativeLayout>
 </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>                
 </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        style="@style/MatchParentMatchParent"
        />
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/color_white"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp">

        <androidx.percentlayout.widget.PercentRelativeLayout
            style="@style/MatchParentMatchParent">

            <TextView
                style="@style/WrapContentWrapContent"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:paddingStart="50dp"
                android:paddingEnd="50dp"
                android:text="@string/title_welcome"
                android:textColor="@color/color_dark"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="10%"/>

            <TextView
                style="@style/WrapContentWrapContent"
                android:layout_below="@id/text_nav_drawer_name"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:paddingStart="50dp"
                android:paddingEnd="50dp"
                android:text="@string/msg_available_passes"
                android:textColor="@color/color_blue"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_marginBottomPercent="6%"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="2%" />


            <androidx.percentlayout.widget.PercentRelativeLayout
                style="@style/MatchParentZeroHeight"
                android:layout_below="@id/text_nav_drawer_message"
                android:importantForAccessibility="no"
                app:layout_heightPercent="7.1%"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <View
                    style="@style/MatchParentZeroHeight"
                    android:background="@color/color_grey"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="1%"/>

                <TextView
                    style="@style/NavMenuTextButton"
                   />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="16dp"
                    android:layout_height="16dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="14.5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="90dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/textview_round_secondary"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                    android:textSize="10sp"/>

            </androidx.percentlayout.widget.PercentRelativeLayout>

            <androidx.percentlayout.widget.PercentRelativeLayout
                style="@style/MatchParentZeroHeight"
                android:importantForAccessibility="no"
                app:layout_heightPercent="7.1%"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <View
                    style="@style/MatchParentZeroHeight"
                    android:background="@color/color_grey"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="1%"/>

                <TextView
                    style="@style/NavMenuTextButton"/>

            </androidx.percentlayout.widget.PercentRelativeLayout>

            <androidx.percentlayout.widget.PercentRelativeLayout
                style="@style/MatchParentZeroHeight"
                android:layout_below="@id/percent_menu_buy_passes"
                android:importantForAccessibility="no"
                app:layout_heightPercent="7.1%"
                android:visibility="gone">


                <View                  
                    android:id="@+id/view_menu_divider_planner"
                    style="@style/MatchParentZeroHeight"
                    android:background="@color/color_grey"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="1%"/>

                <TextView
                    style="@style/NavMenuTextButton"
                    android:layout_below="@id/view_menu_divider_planner"
                    android:text="@string/action_trip_planner"/>

            </androidx.percentlayout.widget.PercentRelativeLayout>

            <androidx.percentlayout.widget.PercentRelativeLayout
                style="@style/MatchParentZeroHeight"
                android:layout_below="@id/percent_menu_planner"
                android:importantForAccessibility="no"
                app:layout_heightPercent="7.1%"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <View
                    style="@style/MatchParentZeroHeight"
                    android:background="@color/color_grey"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="1%"/>

                <TextView
                    style="@style/NavMenuTextButton"
                    android:layout_below="@id/view_menu_divider_my_trips"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/desc_my_trips_button"
                    android:text="@string/action_my_trips"/>

            </androidx.percentlayout.widget.PercentRelativeLayout>

            <androidx.percentlayout.widget.PercentRelativeLayout
                style="@style/MatchParentZeroHeight"
                android:layout_below="@id/percent_menu_my_trips"
                android:importantForAccessibility="no"
                app:layout_heightPercent="7.1%"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <View
                    style="@style/MatchParentZeroHeight"
                    android:background="@color/color_grey"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="1%"/>

                <TextView
                    style="@style/NavMenuTextButton"
                    android:layout_below="@id/view_menu_divider_favorites"
                    android:text="@string/action_favorites"/>

            </androidx.percentlayout.widget.PercentRelativeLayout>

            <androidx.percentlayout.widget.PercentRelativeLayout
                style="@style/MatchParentZeroHeight"
                android:layout_below="@id/percent_menu_favorites"
                android:importantForAccessibility="no"
                app:layout_heightPercent="7.1%"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <View
                    style="@style/MatchParentZeroHeight"
                    android:background="@color/color_grey"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="1%"/>

                <TextView
                    style="@style/NavMenuTextButton"
                    android:layout_below="@id/view_menu_divider_stops_nearby"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/desc_nearby_stops_button"
                    android:text="@string/title_nearby_stops"/>

            </androidx.percentlayout.widget.PercentRelativeLayout>

            <androidx.percentlayout.widget.PercentRelativeLayout
                style="@style/MatchParentZeroHeight"
                android:layout_below="@id/percent_menu_stops_nearby"
                android:importantForAccessibility="no"
                app:layout_heightPercent="7.1%">

                <View
                    style="@style/MatchParentZeroHeight"
                    android:background="@color/color_grey"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="1%"/>

                <TextView
                    style="@style/NavMenuTextButton"
                  android:layout_below="@id/view_menu_divider_settings"
                    android:text="@string/action_settings"/>

            </androidx.percentlayout.widget.PercentRelativeLayout>

            <androidx.percentlayout.widget.PercentRelativeLayout
                style="@style/MatchParentWrapContent"
                android:importantForAccessibility="no"
                android:visibility="gone"
                tools:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_heightPercent="7.1%"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="69.0%">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                />

            </androidx.percentlayout.widget.PercentRelativeLayout>
            <androidx.percentlayout.widget.PercentRelativeLayout
                style="@style/MatchParentWrapContent"
                android:importantForAccessibility="no"
                android:visibility="gone"
                tools:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_heightPercent="7.1%">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="110dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                />

            </androidx.percentlayout.widget.PercentRelativeLayout>
            <androidx.percentlayout.widget.PercentRelativeLayout
                style="@style/MatchParentWrapContent"
                android:importantForAccessibility="no"
                android:visibility="gone"
                tools:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_heightPercent="7.1%"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/black_link"
                />
                <View
                    style="@style/MatchParentZeroHeight"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="@color/color_grey"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="1%"/>

            </androidx.percentlayout.widget.PercentRelativeLayout>
            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_menu_divider_settings_below"
                style="@style/MatchParentZeroHeight"
                android:layout_below="@id/percent_menu_settings"
                android:background="@color/color_grey"
                app:layout_heightPercent="0.1%"/>

            <TextView
                style="@style/WrapContentWrapContent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:textColor="@color/color_blue"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                app:layout_marginLeftPercent="15%"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="92.5%"/>

        </androidx.percentlayout.widget.PercentRelativeLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Try to add android:layout_gravity="bottom" to the Toolbar

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that moves the whole toolbar to the bottom i just want the toolbar title to move just like a normal collapsing layout

Answer (score 0):

There are more Views in your xml code and it takes me time to modify them instead of that i will give you a hint so try to modify it.

**The xml code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activity.NewsReaderActivity">


<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavi"

/>

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/dabdamis" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Put this in your `onCreate` Method

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
```

also use this below code for the title of the toolbar

```
    //set title of the  toolbar
    collapsing_toolbar.setTitle= "Your Title"
```

`collapsing_toolbar` is the Id of my CollapsinToolbar so id it using `findViewById`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but could not fix my issue. i have a feeling that this is due to the custom toolbar will need to try to come up with a way around this

Comment: Did you remove the defualt toolbar?